# Verify the user's password in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

My requirement is to validate the password entered by a user is the correct password with which he had logged-in. So, I have written the below code, but it is always saying that "Not logged-in". Any help?

```pascal
var
    DomainName,UserName,BackwardSlashString,DomainUserName : String;
    ServerDetailsInputPage : TInputQueryWizardPage;
    hToken, LoginOk : INTEGER; 

function LogonUser(lpszUsername,lpszDomain,lpszPassword: string; 
    dwLogonType,dwLogonProvider: INTEGER; var hToken: INTEGER): INTEGER;
external 'LogonUserA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    DomainName:= ExpandConstant(GetEnv('USERDOMAIN'));
    UserName := ExpandConstant( +GetUserNameString);
    BackwardSlashString := '\'
    DomainUserName := DomainName + BackwardSlashString + UserName;
    ServerDetailsInputPage := 
       CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,'','','Please enter following data and click Next.');
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Add('IP Address',False);
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Add('Port Number',False);
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Add('Domain Name\User Name',False);
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Add('Password',True);
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Values[1] := '80';
    ServerDetailsInputPage.Values[2] := DomainUserName;
end;

function RunAsUser(): BOOLEAN; 
var
    Passwd : String;
begin
    DomainName := ExpandConstant(GetEnv('USERDOMAIN'));
    UserName := ExpandConstant( +GetUserNameString);
    Passwd := ServerDetailsInputPage.Values[3];
    LoginOk := LogonUser(UserName,DomainName,Passwd,1,0,hToken); 
    if (not (LoginOk=0)) then
    begin
        MsgBox('successfully logged-in', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Result := true;
    end

    else if (LoginOk=0) then
    begin
        MsgBox('Not logged-in', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Result := false;
    end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;

    if CurPageID = ServerDetailsInputPage.ID then
    begin
        if not RunAsUser then
        begin
            MsgBox('Please enter correct Password!', mbError, MB_OK);
            Result:=False;
        end;
    end;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    PrevInstallPath : String;
    ResultCode : Integer;
    FXStopStatus : Boolean;
begin
    Result:=True;
end;
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  The user already provided a valid password, required to login to Windows and get your installer to run in the first place.  An installer that asks for the user's password sets off lots of alarm bells, make sure your Cancel button works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, your [`LogonUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) function prototype is wrong as well as its call. You can't mix data types of the function prototype and you can't use arbitrary values in a function call. You can use something like this instead:

```pascal
[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const  
  LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
  LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
  LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
  LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
  LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
  LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
  LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
  LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2;
  LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;

  ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
  ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE = 1326;

function LogonUser(lpszUsername, lpszDomain, lpszPassword: string;
  dwLogonType, dwLogonProvider: DWORD; var phToken: THandle): BOOL;
  external 'LogonUser{#AW}@advapi32.dll stdcall';

var
  ServerDetailsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function TryLogonUser(const Domain, UserName, Password: string; 
  var ErrorCode: Longint): Boolean;
var
  Token: THandle;
begin
  Result := LogonUser(UserName, Domain, Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, Token);
  ErrorCode := DLLGetLastError;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  UserName: string;
begin
  UserName := AddBackslash(GetEnv('USERDOMAIN')) + GetUserNameString;
  ServerDetailsPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 
    '', '', 'Please enter following data and click Next.');
  ServerDetailsPage.Add('IP Address', False);
  ServerDetailsPage.Add('Port Number', False);
  ServerDetailsPage.Add('Domain Name\User Name', False);
  ServerDetailsPage.Add('Password', True);
  ServerDetailsPage.Values[1] := '80';
  ServerDetailsPage.Values[2] := UserName;
end;

procedure ParseDomainUserName(const Value: string; var Domain,
  UserName: string);
var
  DelimPos: Integer;
begin
  DelimPos := Pos('\', Value);
  if DelimPos = 0 then
  begin
    Domain := '.';
    UserName := Value;
  end
  else
  begin
    Domain := Copy(Value, 1, DelimPos - 1);
    UserName := Copy(Value, DelimPos + 1, MaxInt);
  end;
end;

function ServerDetailsLogonUser: Boolean; 
var
  Domain: string;
  UserName: string;
  Password: string;
  ErrorCode: Longint;
begin
  ParseDomainUserName(ServerDetailsPage.Values[2], Domain, UserName);
  Password := ServerDetailsPage.Values[3];
  Result := TryLogonUser(Domain, UserName, Password, ErrorCode);

  case ErrorCode of
    ERROR_SUCCESS:
      MsgBox('Logon successful!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE:
      MsgBox('The user name or password is incorrect!', mbError, MB_OK);
  else
    MsgBox('Login failed!' + #13#10 + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError),
      mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = ServerDetailsPage.ID then
    Result := ServerDetailsLogonUser;
end;
```