# Is there a way to check if an Application Pool identity is valid?

Tags: iis, inno-setup

Im currently writing a Inno Script setup which adds the program Im installing to the IIS DefaultAppPool, also I have to change the Identity of the Pool to credentials based on the users input.
The problem is that i have no idea how to check if the given Identity is valid. Im using AppCmd which doesn't seem to care if the given username and password are valid, thus it crashes the ApplicationPool after starting the given App at the end.

I've tried to catch the error codes returned by my appcmd command, but there is nothing notable. Im just getting a message that the change was successfull.

Here is the appcmd command im using:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set AppPool DefaultAppPool -processModel.identityTypeSpecificUser -processModel.userName:USERINPUTUSERNAME -processModel.password:USERINPUTPASSWORD
```

Comment: Would this help? [Verify the user's password in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15492357/850848)

Comment: That was precisely what i needed. Thanks a lot.